# Why only some FontAwesome fonts are not showing?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am facing strange issue with **fontawesome version 6 free** library. Only some of the icons are not showing.

**UI Screenshot**

[image]

**FontAwesome all.min.css Source**

[image]

If I use **all.min.js** instead of **all.min.css** everything works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: 1. Change `fa` to `fa-solid`.
2. This icon is introduced in version 6, perhaps you're using font-awesome@5.
These are the possible reasons.

Comment: I tried changing fa to fa-solid but still not working. In fact, classes fa-building-* not working only fa-building is working. tried fa-building-wheat, fa-building-un and fa-building-flag none of these working

Comment: @maddy23285, what is version number of Fontawesome?

Comment: Fontawesome version 6 free

Comment: follow font awesome docs, view this link https://fontawesome.com/icons/building-user?s=solid  and I think the problem will solve.

Comment: @Eng_Farghly I already tried this with no success. But If I use the JS distribution all.min.js instead of CSS this works well. This problem occurs when I use all.min.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by `clearing the browser cache`. Basically, the web fonts of the previous version (5) were cached in the browser and the browser was still referring to the old version web fonts, which is why UI was unable to locate the `content:"\e4da"`.

I found this to be a cause of the issue because the project runs as per expectation in InPrivate/Incognito mode.

**Screenshot of UI in InPrivate/Incognito Mode**

[image]

**Screenshot of UI in Normal Mode**

[image]